# What causes Java programs to die with a hotspot dump with a SIGSEGV in it?

Tags: java, jvm

Well, i have a application running in Java 64bits (6.0_35) in Ubuntu lst 10.04 64bits too. Every time i execute a specific method, my JVM crashes and i'dont have ideia why.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f75e3e639a3, pid=3750, tid=140144311375616
#
# JRE version: 6.0_35-b10
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.10-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libLeituraMFDBin_x64.so+0x99a3]  LeituraMFDBin(char const*, char const*, char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool)+0xebf
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /projetos/trunk_desenvolvimento/hs_err_pid3750.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: You should post the code for that specific method at least

Comment: Looks to me like a problematic native library.

Comment: unfortunately i can't do it, because this method is from a "library.so" and i don't have access to this, but in anothers computers this works fine.

Comment: From link @bmargulies posted, it looks like you resolved the issue. Mind sharing?

Answer (score 4):

You are using a native library: libLeituraMFDBin_x64.so. It is crashing. It has a bug; given some input conditions, it defererences a pointer to invalid memory. It might be as simple as you passing a Java `null` that it fails to check for, or it might be some complex coding error leading to storage corruption. In any case, the library is failing a fundamental test of a JNI library, which is *don't crash*.

You need to take this up with the author of that library. Apparently, problems with this library are commonplace, see [this link](http://www.guj.com.br/java/302771-problemas-com-leitura-mfd---ecf) for an example.

Comment: this post (in the link) is mine. hehehe, and don't have solution.

Comment: i don't think this is a library problem because yesterday was working normally, but today not.

Comment: By definition, JNI libraries should not crash. So, either @Rahul was correct and your hardware has died, or the library has a bug that you have just tickled.

Comment: Can't it be a segfault in the code which only happens in a specific circumstance?

Comment: @user2776409: Obviously it also wasn't working normally on July 17, if that post was in fact yours.  Software bugs don't have to happen all of the time.  They can be exposed by environment changes and many other things.  The point stands that it's a problem occurring in that library, not in Java code.  However, what you pass in to the library might have an effect on it.  For example, if you pass in a null reference and the library doesn't expect one, you could get a segfault in the native code rather than an NPE in Java code.